# openssl s_client troubleshooting validation problem: No SNI provided, CN=invalid

Tags: openssl, client-certificates

given this openssl command I would expect Googles certificate to validate nicely:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.com:443
```

However, on my local machine (MacOs Ventura 13.3.1) I get this response:

Emphasis on the line **"No SNI provided; please fix your client.", CN = invalid2.invalid
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate"**

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect google.com:443 
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=0 OU = "No SNI provided; please fix your client.", CN = invalid2.invalid
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = "No SNI provided; please fix your client.", CN = invalid2.invalid
verify return:1
write W BLOCK
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=No SNI provided; please fix your client./CN=invalid2.invalid
   i:/OU=No SNI provided; please fix your client./CN=invalid2.invalid
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/OU=No SNI provided; please fix your client./CN=invalid2.invalid
issuer=/OU=No SNI provided; please fix your client./CN=invalid2.invalid
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1370 bytes and written 351 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AEAD-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : AEAD-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Start Time: 1682417068
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
```

However, if I try to connect to other sites, I have no problems with the validation.

For instance validation of Microsoft certificate works perfect:

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.microsoft.com:443
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root G2
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Microsoft Corporation, CN = Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 06
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = WA, L = Redmond, O = Microsoft Corporation, CN = www.microsoft.com
verify return:1
write W BLOCK
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=WA/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=www.microsoft.com
   i:/C=US/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 06
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 06
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=US/ST=WA/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=www.microsoft.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Microsoft Corporation/CN=Microsoft Azure TLS Issuing CA 06
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4348 bytes and written 351 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AEAD-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : AEAD-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Start Time: 1682417654
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Also on other servers I get a fine response where the certificate from google.com actually looks OK.

My question is how to troubleshoot this problem on my machine?

Comment: What happens if you use the `-servername` option to `s_client`?  I'd also check `/etc/hosts` for a `google.com` entry.

Comment: with `-servername` option it works, thanks @AndrewHenle. 

Could you post an answer, and I will gladly accept it

Comment: PS. my `/etc/hosts` has no entries that could disturb

Comment: That might not be the root cause - it works without `-servername` on other systems, right?  That means whatever you're connecting to probably isn't the real `google.com`.  Are you behind a corporate firewall that could be doing MITM inspection of your TLS connections?

Comment: You can run `openssl s_client .... | openssl x509 -noout -text` and see what cert you're actually getting.

Comment: I am not behind corporate firewall, and I disconnected from VPN. However, many vpns modify network on the macbook but I am in doubt if that could cause the problem.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I found more info about `-servername` that confirms your suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43785703/using-servername-param-with-openssl-s-client